# Robot framework response to JSON test fails when attribute is not present in response

Tags: robotframework

I'm very new to robotframework and I need to write Robot tests that pass if the next two conditions are valid:

```
Should Not Contain    ${response.json()['errorDetails']['errorDescription']}    ${error1}
Should Not Contain    ${response.json()['errorDetails']['errorCode']}           ${error2}
```

In the case that the response is not an error response, the above conditions will fail because the response doesn't contain the key 'errorDetails'

```
Resolving variable '${response.json()['errorDetails']['errorDescription']}' failed: KeyError: 'errorDetails'
```

For example, this is also a valid response that will not have the 'errorDetails' attribute:

```
{"respStatus":"SUCCESS","respObj":{"message":"Object created"}}
```

**How do I rewrite the test conditions to not fail if the response doesn't contain such attribute 'errorDetails'?**

Answer (score 2):

You can put your check in a keyword and then use `Run keyword if` to trigger your check only when a condition is passed.

here is an example:

```
*** Test cases ***
my_test
    ${json} =  Create Dictionary  foo=bar
    # next statement will not be launched in that case
    # but it will be launched if errorDetails key is present in the JSON
    Run keyword if  'errorDetails' in ${json}  check_error_details  ${json}
    
*** Keywords ***
check_error_details
    [Arguments]  ${json}
    Should Not Contain    ${json['errorDetails']['errorDescription']}    ${error1}
    Should Not Contain    ${json['errorDetails']['errorCode']}           ${error2}
```